# Rails 4 + Sprockets: Allowing the use of js.erb files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ecmascript-6, sprockets

I am attempting to use ES6 syntax in my Rails 4 app and have had some success between the use of [`sprockets-es6 (0.9.2)`](https://github.com/TannerRogalsky/sprockets-es6), `sprockets-rails (3.0.4)` and `sprockets (3.6.0)`.

The only issue I'm having is that my files need to end in `.es6` in order to enable proper compilation and I'd like to be able to use a `.es6.erb` or `.js.erb` file type to allow me to use embedded ruby `<%= foo %>`.

Does anyone know of a way around this?

Comment: Don't use embedded ruby? There are vert few actual cases where its needed. Especially since its compiled at deploy time.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd like to in this instance rather than generating a bunch of ajax calls for things I can do in one line of ruby

Comment: could this help you https://github.com/TannerRogalsky/sprockets-es6 ? http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution? It is rare, but I do need it in one file to check Rails.env.

Comment: no, I didn't.  Had to find a workaround

Comment: I just figured out my issue was using `link_directory` with a directory that has .js.erb files in it. `link_directory` doesn't identify them as javascript files automatically. I was getting Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled but it didn't click for a while. As soon as I used `link` with my .js.erb files, they started working properly. Adding .js as a second argument to `link_directory` fixed my issues :-)

Answer (score 2):

> This question is a few years old and the OP specifies Sprockets 3.6. But I'm guessing many will find this question when looking for a solution to using erb files with a more modern version of sprockets.

If you're using Sprockets 4 and want to use `.js.erb` you'll need to 'register_mime_type'.

e.g. add the following to a new file called `./config/initializer/register_mime_type.rb`

```
Sprockets.register_mime_type 'application/javascript', extensions: ['.js.erb']
```

This is described in [Extending Sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/guides/extending_sprockets.md#adding-erb-support-to-your-extension).